# Mapbox interactivity where values change in information window based on hover using R mapboxapi and mapboxer

Tags: javascript, html, r, mapbox, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to get a mapbox, which changes layers on different zooms, to change values in an information window on mouse hover (like [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/)) using R's `mapboxapi`, `mapboxer`, and `htmlwidgets`. Kyle Walker's provides a great [example of creating a legend](https://walker-data.com/mapboxapi/articles/dynamic-maps.html), which used [this example on creating a legend](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/show-changes-over-time/) and I adapted below, but I'm struggling with translating the html and javascript code into the appropriate html chunk to adapt to my needs. My thinking is that the [mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/) requires pulling from a style, which might need to be upload to mapbox to operate and I need to do this all in html.

```
librarian::shelf(mapboxapi, mapboxer, htmltools, htmlwidgets)

or_evictions <- mapbox_source(
  type = "vector",
  url = paste0("mapbox://docthomas.oregon_evictions") 
)

eviction_map <- 
  mapboxer(zoom = 5.7, style = basemaps$Mapbox$light_v10,
           center = c(-120.5, 44.2),
           token = public_token) %>%
  add_layer(
    style = list(
      id = "county",
      type = "fill",
      source = or_evictions,
      "source-layer" = "counties",
      paint = list(
        "fill-color" = list(
          "interpolate",
          list("linear"),
          list("get", "avg_evr_all"),
          0, "#FFFFFF", 
          2, "#fecc5c", 
          6, "#fd8d3c", 
          12, "#f03b20", 
          25, "#51087e"
        ),
        "fill-opacity" = list(
          "case",
          list("==", list("get", "avg_evr_all"), NA),
          0.1,
          0.4
        )
      ),
      maxzoom = 7
    ),
    popup = "{{NAME}}<br/>Eviction Rate: {{avg_evr_all}}%")  %>%
  add_layer(
    style = list(
      id = "tracts",
      type = "fill",
      source = or_evictions,
      "source-layer" = "tracts",
      paint = list(
        "fill-color" = list(
          "interpolate",
          list("linear"),
          list("get", "avg_evr_all"),
          0, "#FFFFFF", 
          2, "#fecc5c", 
          6, "#fd8d3c", 
          12, "#f03b20", 
          25, "#51087e"
        ),
        "fill-opacity" = list(
          "case",
          list("==", list("get", "avg_evr_all"), NA),
          0.1,
          0.4
        )
      ),
      minzoom = 7
    ),
    popup = "{{NAME}}<br/>Eviction Rate: {{avg_evr_all}}%")

eviction_map
#
# Add legend and other dynamics
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

style <- htmltools::HTML(
  "
  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

    h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #legend {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 10px;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #ffffff80;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    z-index: 1002;
    }

    .content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .row {
    height: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .colors {
    background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #FFFFFF, 
    #fecc5c, 
    #fd8d3c, 
    #f03b20, 
    #51087e
    );
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .label {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    }
    </style>
  "
)

legend <- htmltools::HTML(
  '
<div id="legend">
<div class="content">
<h2>Eviction Rate</h2>
<div class="row colors"></div>
<div class="row labels">
<div class="label">0%</div>
<div class="label">   </div>
<div class="label">25+%</div>
</div>
</div>
  '
)

info <- htmltools::HTML(
 ' 
<div id="info"></div>
<div class="map-overlay" id="features">
<h2>Yearly average eviction rate</h2>
<div id="avg_evr_all"><p>Hover over a county or tract!</p></div>
</div>


map.on("mousemove", (event) => {
  const avg_evr_all = .queryRenderedFeatures(event.point, {
    layers: ["or_eviction"]
  });
  document.getElementById("pd").innerHTML = avg_evr_all.length
    ? `<h3>${avg_evr_all[0].properties.name}</h3><p><strong><em>${avg_evr_all[0].properties.density}</strong> people per square mile</em></p>`
    : `<p>Hover over a state!</p>`;
});

  '
)

# test <- 
  eviction_map %>%
  htmlwidgets::prependContent(style) %>%
  htmlwidgets::appendContent(legend) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::appendContent(info)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Below is an example of what I'm getting. Ideally the bottom of the legend would show a different rate when hovering on either a county or a census tract (after zooming in). I can get a popup to work but really need hover functionality.

[image: example map]

Comment: I think that all you need to do is surround the JS with script tags. That's your `info <- htmltools::HTML(...`. Put `<script>` before `map.on...` and at the end, before the closing `'`, add `</script>`. Let me know if that doesn't fix it. (You can't just add JS to HTML, you have to tell the HTML that it's JS.)

Comment: Thanks Kat, I ultimately abandoned this approach for raw Mapbox coding. It was a bit of a learning curve but has much more flexibility. Here's my [first draft using Mapbox coding](https://evictionresearch.net/oregon/maps/post.html).